# GA4 page_views metrics much lower than UA

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We've added a GA4 instance in parallel with UA -- the page_views reports show significantly less than UA. Using google tag assistant I'm seeing the same history change event firing for both tag id's.

Any ideas on the cause?

Comment: show the collect network calls on history change for both.

Comment: I am seeing network calls for both -- POST for GA4 and GET for UA.

Comment: check the tid from GA4, it should be your data stream's measurement id.

Comment: it has the correct ID

Comment: ok, if you're sure that the history change correctly fires one time both UA and GA4 pageviews, plus the tid in the GA4 call is fine, then there's another popular possibility: UA receives calls from pages/sites/subdomains that were forgotten during GA4 migration. In your analytics, start breaking the pageviews by pages. See which pages contribute most to the difference. Pages, hostnames, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Google Anlaytics 4 is little more than 1/3 of "page_views" as Events, compared to Universal Analytics "Pageviews"

I don't know what the full reason is, but part of it, for us, was that Google didn't have a way to support GA4 on AMP pages. A few days before the switchover, they did add recognition for AMP w/ GA4. And now, after some different tests, we are getting results for AMP pages included.

Helpful, but still does not account for loss of 2/3 of activity. Sorry, only a partial fix for us.